# Should I be using distinct / distinct on to remove duplicates caused by a 1:many join?

Tags: postgresql

Revision to my previous question as I continue to try different solutions. `select distinct on` is getting me very close to my intended output but I'm not quite able to make it fully work without adding to the GROUP BY statement. I'm now wondering if I should be focusing on making `select distinct on` work rather than trying to improve the original table join. Other questions that I have read state that this is more of a 'band-aid' approach. Is there a best practice that I should be following? Original question below:

I am having trouble finding the best way to join a 1:many table without increasing my output with duplicates. I have tried using `select distinct on v.visit.id` which gets me close, but only if I change the GROUP BY statement, which will mess up my desired output. My end goal is to calculate both how long the patient/visit was in the OR and how long the surgeon was scheduled for their block from the tables below:

Table 1 (visit)

| visit_id |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 321 |

Table 2 (pat_phy_relation_table)

| patphys_pat_num | patphys_rel_type | patphys_phy_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ATTENDING | 1306 |
| 321 | ATTENDING | 1306 |

Table 3 (physician_table1)

| phys1_num | phys1_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1306 | Dr X |

Table 4 (multi_app_documentation) (OR times)

| nsma1_patnum | nsma1_code | nsma1_ans |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ORINTIME | 1037 |
| 123 | OROUT | 1352 |
| 321 | ORINTIME | 0723 |
| 321 | OROUT | 0952 |

Table 5 (ews_location_table2) (block times)

| esla1_loca | esla1_date | esla1_bt_beg | esla1_bt_end | esla1_bt_surg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OR3 | 2021-09-02 | {'07:00:00',,,,,,,,,} | {'17:00:00',,,,,,,,,} | {001306,,,,,,,,,} |
| OR3 | 2021-09-16 | {'07:00:00',,,,,,,,,} | {'17:00:00',,,,,,,,,} | {001306,,,,,,,,,} |
| OR3 | 2021-09-30 | {'07:00:00',,,,,,,,,} | {'17:00:00',,,,,,,,,} | {001306,,,,,,,,,} |

Expected Results

| total_visits | or_hours_utilized | total_block_hours | surgeon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 9:31:00 | 30:00:00 | Dr X |

Actual Results

| total_visits | or_hours_utilized | total_block_hours | surgeon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 28:33:00 | 60:00:00 | Dr X |

My assumption is that since I am using an inner join for table 5, my results are being duplicated by the # of returned rows. However, I'm not aware of another way to join this table as all of my other joins are 1:1. This is the only 1:many relationship. I just can't seem to think of a solution as table 5 has no related columns to the visit table.

I'm currently looking into subqueries, but I'm not familiar enough with them to know if I can handle the table 5 calculations in one and just pass back the results to the main query.

I've tried to strip out information that is irrelevant to the question, but let me know if I can slim down anything else. Query below:

```
select 
count(v.visit_id) as total_visits,
sum(mad2.nsma1_ans::time - mad.nsma1_ans::time) as or_hours_utilized,
sum(esla1_bt_end[1] - esla1_bt_beg[1]) as total_block_hours,
pt1.phys1_name as surgeon
from visit as v
inner join pat_phy_relation_table as pprt 
    on pprt.patphys_pat_num = v.visit_id
inner join physician_table1 as pt1
    on pt1.phys1_num = pprt.patphys_phy_num
inner join ews_location_table2 elt2
    on lpad(pt1.phys1_num::varchar, 6, '0') = any (elt2.esla1_bt_surg)
    and esla1_loca in ('OR1','OR2','OR3','OR4')
    and esla1_date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-30'
inner join multi_app_documentation mad2 
    on mad2.nsma1_patnum = v.visit_id
    and mad2.nsma1_code = 'OROUT' --only pulling visits/physicians with an OROUT    
inner join multi_app_documentation mad 
    on mad.nsma1_patnum = v.visit_id
    and mad.nsma1_code = 'ORINTIME' --only pulling visits/physicians with an ORINTIME
where v.visit_admit_date = '2021-09-01'
group by pt1.phys1_name
```

Comment: I didn't read this closely, but perhaps `DISTINCT ON` with an `ORDER BY` clause can remove those duplicates that you do not want.

Comment: I have tried using select distinct on (v.visit_id) which I agree should remove duplicates, but that would require me to add visit_id into the GROUP BY clause which causes my output to change.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not aware of another way to join this table as all of my other joins are 1:1. This is the only 1:many relationship

Not quite, both your `pat_phy_relation_table` and your `ews_location_table2` have 1:many relations to the surgeons (`physician_table1`). So really it's a many:many relationship between patients and or blocks - but that's not what you want, you can't use a JOIN there. Instead, do two independent [`LATERAL` subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL), for each surgeon:

```
select
  a.total_visits,
  a.or_hours_utilized,
  pt1.phys1_name as surgeon,
  b.total_block_hours
from
  physician_table1 as pt1,
  lateral (
    select
      count(v.visit_id) as total_visits,
      sum(mad2.nsma1_ans::time - mad.nsma1_ans::time) as or_hours_utilized,
    from visit as v
    inner join pat_phy_relation_table as pprt
      on pprt.patphys_pat_num = v.visit_id
    inner join multi_app_documentation mad2
      on mad2.nsma1_patnum = v.visit_id
      and mad2.nsma1_code = 'OROUT' -- only pulling visits/physicians with an OROUT    
    inner join multi_app_documentation mad 
      on mad.nsma1_patnum = v.visit_id
      and mad.nsma1_code = 'ORINTIME' -- only pulling visits/physicians with an ORINTIME
    where
      pt1.phys1_num = pprt.patphys_phy_num -- joining against the particular physician
      and v.visit_admit_date = '2021-09-01'
  ) as a,
  lateral (
    select
      sum(esla1_bt_end[1] - esla1_bt_beg[1]) as total_block_hours,
    from
      ews_location_table2 elt2
    where
      lpad(pt1.phys1_num::varchar, 6, '0') = any (elt2.esla1_bt_surg) -- joining against the particular physician
      and esla1_loca in ('OR1','OR2','OR3','OR4')
      and esla1_date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-30'
  ) as b;
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with subqueries. I'm running into an error where the 'pt1 table cannot be referenced from this part of the query'. Would I need to add it to each subquery? But if I do that I would need to add other tables for the join criteria which doesn't sound right.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the `LATERAL` keyword

Comment: Am I still able to group by physician name in this scenario? When added, I get an error asking for all of my select columns to also be added. It seems to think that they are not already aggregate functions.

Comment: It does implicitly group by the physician (not by it name but by the entire row) due to how the subqueries are evaluated - once for each `pt1` entry.